# Azure DevOps problem to create project via REST call containing german umlauts

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I have an admin script that creates Azure DevOps projects via calls to the REST API. This works fine as long as the name or description arguments contain no special characters. If for example german umlauts are in the description, the call fails.

This works:

```
 curl -k -D- -X POST -d '{"name":"Phantom","capabilities":{"processTemplate":{"templateTypeId":"6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45"},"versioncontrol":{"sourceControlType":"Git"}},"visibility":"private","description":"Innocent description without umlauts"}' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic secretauthorizationtoken=' https://dev.azure.com/AdminPlayground/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

this one throws an exception:

```
curl -k -D- -X POST -d '{"name":"Phantom","capabilities":{"processTemplate":{"templateTypeId":"6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45"},"versioncontrol":{"sourceControlType":"Git"}},"visibility":"private","description":"Funny description with strange äöüß chars"}' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Basic secretauthorizationtoken=' https://dev.azure.com/AdminPlayground/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0-preview.4
```

The exception is:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: projectToCreate","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Has anybody experienced similar behavior, and could perhaps suggest a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: try to add `charset=utf-8` to the `Content-Type`, e.g. `'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'`

Comment: I tried the command with charset=utf-8 in the Content-Type Header - same result.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the data format problem caused by the special characters in description.

Kindly check if it can be solved by adding the correct encoding format into the `-ContentType`，

For example `-ContentType 'application/json;charset=utf -8'`
[image]

Comment: I tried the command with charset=utf-8 in the Content-Type Header - same result.

Comment: @Sam You could also give a try with using postman to call same  Rest API to create project. It's available to use `Funny description with strange äöüß chars` both use web portal and postman to call Rest API in my side. If it also works, this may not related to API itself. Will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Sorry, Patrick, I somehow missed your reply.
I wasn't aware of "postman" - is there a quickstart for using it for this experiment?

Comment: Hi Sam, it's just a tool, you could use same Rest API in the tool to call it. If will return API response. And then you could check update in Azure DevOps side. For tutorials, you could kindly refer  **Testing Azure DevOps APIs Using Postman** in this link:http://apievangelist.com/2020/01/22/three-ways-to-use-postman-and-azure-devops/